# Dinamically modifying attributes of images on posts

Tags: images, filters, customization

Using the filter `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` I'm able, for example, to add an attribute to image attachments:

```
function my_filter( $attr, $attachment, $size )
{
    $attr['data-custom'] = 'hello';

    return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'my_filter', 10, 3 );
```

However this filter does **not** affects `img`s in posts.

I already managed to do this with `image_send_to_editor` filter, but this way the attributes become "*hard-coded*" into the post's source so I'm not satisfied with this approach.

Is there a way to add/edit **posts** images' attributes dinamically as the `img`s are rendered into the page source?

In other words, is there a way to extend `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` to images in posts?

Comment: Did you try by filtering `the_content` for `img` tag?

Comment: At the end (see my answer) I ended filtering `the_content`. But I identified images via string parsing. Is there a way to get and edit just `img`s ?

Comment: Another approach is to add a new button to the editor that opens the media window and inserts your own custom shortcode for images. You can then insert whatever markup you want when `the_content` is rendered and your shortcode function executes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such filter to do that directly.

The only way is intercept the post's content and modify it:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'FilterImages', 0 );
function FilterImages( $content )
{
    // parse $content looking for <img .... />
    // modify $content if it needs to be modified

    return $content;
}
```

I managed to do what I needed to do with some string manipulation.

I guess also [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) can be used if the content manipulation task is not trivial.